# postgreSQL Adding New Key with value if it doesnt exist and edit it if it does

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I'm trying to run the following but it's not updating columns with NULL values or columns that do not have this key:

```
update A a set 
a.jsonbcolumn = ('{"key":' 1 '}')
```

I'm using postgres 9.6.3 and jsonb_set does not work for me. Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jsonb_set()` is the way to go:

```
update a
  set jsonbcolumn = jsonb_set(jsonbcolumn, '{key}', '1');
```

If it does not create the key, this is probably becase the column value is `NULL` rather than an empty JSON. In that case use `coalesce()`:

```
update a
  set jsonbcolumn = jsonb_set(coalesce(jsonbcolumn,'{}'), '{key}', '1');
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/MSU66547